# Python KeyError: 'OUTPUT_PATH'

Tags: python

I'm trying to run the following python code for to exercise

```
#!/bin/python3

import os
import sys

#
# Complete the maximumDraws function below.
#
def maximumDraws(n):
    return n+1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    t = int(input())

    for t_itr in range(t):
        n = int(input())

        result = maximumDraws(n)

        fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

but i get this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "maximumdraws.py", line 13, in <module>
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
  File "/home/inindekikral/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'OUTPUT_PATH'
```

My Operation System is Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon.
What i have to do?

Comment: you have to define OUTPUT_PATH as an exported env. variable. Or better: use command line arguments...

Comment: Did you set the environment variable 'OUTPUT_PATH'? In bash, you can set it by running:

`export OUTPUT_PATH='myfile'`

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

os.environ lets you access environment variables from your python script, it seems you do not have an environment variable with name OUTPUT_PATH. From the terminal you run your python script, before running your python code set an environment variable with name OUTPUT_PATH such as:

```
export OUTPUT_PATH="home/inindekikral/Desktop/output.txt"
```

Your python script will create a file at that location.

Comment: it still outputs error, I am really surprised that the question which is being viewed nearly 1000 times and commented by multiple people is getting downvote and the answer which does not even solve the problem gets an upvote.

Comment: @SDE I explained what os.environ does and why op encounters such an error. I am really surprised how the answer "you do not have an environment variable with name OUTPUT_PATH" does not solve the problem. You need to create an environment variable called OUTPUT_PATH that shows path to file you want to create, that is it. Here I specifically answered according to op's situation, he uses Linux operating system and his username is "inendekikral".

Comment: Actually, this looks like it would give an IsADirectoryError so instead he should use just "output.txt" or "home/inindekikral/Desktop/output.txt"

Answer (score 12):

I'm sure there are other ways to do this, but for Hackerrank exercises, the file pointer was opened this way:

```
fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
```

... and I want it to just go to standard output.

I just changed that line to

```
fptr = sys.stdout   # stdout is already an open stream
```

and it does what I want.

Note that on the one hand, `os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH']` is a string, while `fptr` is a stream/file pointer.

Variations:

1. If you want to write to a file, you can do it the way suggested above (setting the `OUTPUT_PATH` environment variable).
2. Or, you can set the os.environ directly in python, e.g.

   `os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'] = 'junk.txt'  # before you open the fptr!`

Comment: Yes you are right , at least I am from HackerRank  :)

Answer (score 1):

A `KeyError` means that an element doesn’t have a key. So that means that `os.environ` doesn’t have the key `'OUTPUT_PATH'`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, change the path of the python code to your local path.

```
fptr = open("./result.output", 'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hackerrank sends output to a file, but for practice locally, the output can be printed.

You can remove the use of ftpr by commenting out these lines
fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w') and
fptr.close()

And replace line fptr.write(str(result) + '\n') with print(str(result) + '\n')

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

t = int(input())

for t_itr in range(t):

    n = int(input())

    result = maximumDraws(n)

    print(str(result) + '\n')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).